# Starting X as a normal user

Tags: xorg, permissions, root

I am only able to launch startx as the root user, but I would like to run it as a normal user instead, because apparently `xrdp` won't let me open a remote session when X is running as root.

Every time I try to launch startx as a normal user it immediately crashes saying that the exiting process has been successful (haha, how funny).

This is what I have tried doing so far:

- Changing the owner of .Xauthority to my user
- Deleting all .Xauthority-related files
- Adding my user to the `video` group
- Reconfiguring `xorg`
- Uninstalling and reinstalling `xorg`
- Setting permission to launch X to `anybody` in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`

All to no avail, I can still only run `startx` as root. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change the owner of the `.ICEauthority` as well, which was still owned by `root`:

`sudo chown {user}:{usergroup} .ICEauthority`

Comment: Do you mean the `~/.ICEauthority` ? In my case (14.04.x) ownership is already that of the user...  ( 0_o ? )

Comment: Uh that was long time ago, I am not sure anymore :P